# LINQ To SQL and ASP.NET Website data issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following issue with the website deployment that has LINQ to SQL.
the following are the connection properties on the dbml side.

[image]

This is the entry on my web.config file

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MYSQLSERVER;
Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

On the partial class constructor (VB.NET)

```
Public Sub New()  MyBase.New(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        OnCreated()
End Sub
```

This website is running successfully from inside the VS2010.

However, I deploy the website on IIS and the pages are rendering except for the data part where the data is not loaded from the database.

More Information:

It is working when I am using Visual Studio Development Server. When I change to use Local IIS web server there is issue. When I check the IIS express checkbox it works fine.

Additional Information: – 
I am on a XP box with IIS 5.1 I did select ASP.NET 4.0 and do the aspnet_regiis - i under the .NET framework 4.0 the mapping between IIS and .NET is correct.

Any inputs on how this can be mitigated?

Comment: Are you getting *no data* or is there an error of some kind?  Is it possible that when deployed, you're pointing to another database which doesn't have the data, but the schema in place?

Comment: Can your Full IIS access db? Have you tested that?

Comment: @casperOne - I have a dropdown the values are from DB and it is empty. This is on one page. In another asp.net page for a similar dropdown I am getting a "object reference error" which basically calls a method which uses LINQ query to get the values.

Comment: @Mohsen Afshin - I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You said your project works in VS. Once you build your app, VS run your website in IIS Express. Since you say that everything works great in deployment mode except data part, so the problem can be your  IIS

Comment: It is working when I am using Visual Studio Development Server. When I change to use Local IIS web server there is issue. When I check the IIS express checkbox it works fine.

Comment: As Mohsen implied, have you granted the ASPNET account access to the database? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317012

Comment: @AndrewMorton - The database is maintained by a different dept and getting access to it is not easy. Can I configure my domain user account on my webserver to access and accomplish this?

Comment: @kalls From that comment, it sounds like you should be contacting that other department for login details. You don't want to be using your user account as the identity for an application pool on a web server, for security reasons.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Thanks Andrew. I am currently using IIS 5.1 from my local machine to simulate the web server. So there is no application pool that can be configured I guess.

Comment: @kalls You can supply credentials in the connection string. I think you should consult the department looking after the database for advice compliant with your company's security policy.